# Not able to save after deleting rows using EPPlus

Tags: epplus

I have a very simple code to open a copy template excel file put some data into it and delete the remaining empty rows. This works with most of the template files but with few of them i get exception when i try to save the file after deleting not required rows.

In the sample code i have omitted the data addition code and just kept the delete row functionality. When i run this code i get error if i try to delete rows after 1025.

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                FileInfo fis = new FileInfo(@"D:\ExcelTest\TestFile.xlsx");
                FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(fis.DirectoryName, Guid.NewGuid() + fis.Extension));
                fis.CopyTo(fi.FullName);

                using (ExcelPackage excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(fi))
                {
                    ExcelWorksheet worksheet = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets["C3R"];

                    int rowstodelete = (171 * 6) - 23;
                    worksheet.DeleteRow(24, rowstodelete, true);
                    excelPackage.Save();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
```

System.InvalidOperationException: Error saving file D:\ExcelTest\fabf5a3f-714f-4422-a760-73190f34b951.xlsx ---> System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.\r\n   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)\r\n   at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorksheet.UpdateRowCellData(StreamWriter sw)\r\n   at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorksheet.SaveXml(Stream stream)\r\n   at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorksheet.SaveHandler(ZipOutputStream stream, CompressionLevel compressionLevel, String fileName)\r\n   at OfficeOpenXml.Packaging.ZipPackagePart.WriteZip(ZipOutputStream os)\r\n   at OfficeOpenXml.Packaging.ZipPackage.Save(Stream stream)\r\n   at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage.Save()\r\n   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\r\n   at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage.Save()\r\n   at ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\sm511\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs:line 27

[The excel file causing problem](https://gofile.io/?c=mbtYdG)

Comment: Link to test file causing exception https://gofile.io/?c=PJWL1Y

Comment: I think you found a bug.  The error is way in the weeds of the Worksheet code.  Looks like the formula index is messed up.  You might want to post on the epplus github page.

Comment: already posted but no response from them. https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/issues/488